Improving Time Series Visualization for Multiple Variables
I'm seeking advice on how to enhance a time series visualization I've created. Currently, I have plotted a line chart to compare the rate of change of deaths for multiple countries during covid19. However, the countries are overlapping one another, resulting in a very cluttered and messy chart.

Here's what I've done so far:

Plotted a line chart for each country's death rate changes over time.
Used different colors for each country.

The issues I'm facing:

The lines overlap too much, making it difficult to distinguish between different countries.
The chart is visually overwhelming and hard to interpret.

How could I improve this visualization? I am open with using other types of charts.

@μίαμπύρα hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I am not connecting the death rate to something else. The point of this project is improving an existing visualization. For context, this is the original visualization: https://rpubs.com/Giulliansn/Assignment_2_S3852780

@μίαμπύρα I am not allowed to create an interactive chart. It will be a static chart printed on a PDF poster

What's the point of the chart? Sharing that can likely provide other alternatives. For example, if it's to illustrate something related to one country, you could have that country's line be solid and the others "transparent", i.e. a color more like the background

I dont find the graph particularily messy. Except perhaps legibility of some of the country names. try placing them slightly differently.

Separate the Countries. I agree that it is very hard to make sense when they are all on top of each other.
This is a very quick layout to show you the idea:


Thanks for the reply. That was my initial thought as well. However, is there any other types of chart that I could implement?
